# How to define a conditon/validator to prevent transition without entering workload on jira workflow

Tags: jira

On jira workflow,

I must define a rule that prevents moving an issue to "Resolved" state, if there is no workload for the issue. So workload will be a "must" to move issue to "Resolved" state.

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: There is a 'required field' validator

Comment: In "Add Validator To Transition" page there are only two validators:

1) Permission Validator
2) User Permission Validator

Comment: Sorry it's not in JIRA standard, you need to have JIRA Suite Utilities addon installed.

Comment: Yes I've added the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installation **Jira Suite Utilities** plugin. New validators become available.

You must select the "Resolve Issue" transition and add "**Σ Time Spent**" validator to transition.

Now workload is mandatory to resolve an issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Fields required` validator from `JIRA Suite Utilities` addon

Select field: `time spent`

Comment: @Yazan - this does provide an answer and is almost the same as the answer that was written & accepted by author of the question